# t-sql : Error converting data type varchar to numeric in then statement

Tags: t-sql

I cannot understand the error because I'm not trying to convert to numeric the variable @FQTROQ.

```
declare @FQTROQ varchar(30)
declare @FQNUTQ decimal(6,0)
set @FQTROQ = 'R-354'
set @FQNUTQ = 100

SELECT ( CASE WHEN (@FQTROQ is not null and @FQTROQ <> '')
THEN ( @FQTROQ )
ELSE ( @FQNUTQ ) END ) AS Numero_Troquel
```

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @FQTROQ varchar(30)
declare @FQNUTQ decimal(6,0)
set @FQTROQ = 'R-354'
set @FQNUTQ = 100

SELECT CASE WHEN (@FQTROQ is not null and @FQTROQ <> '')
THEN @FQTROQ
ELSE CAST(@FQNUTQ AS VARCHAR(30)) END AS Numero_Troquel
```

You need to cast the `DECIMAL` as a `VARCHAR` so that the output from the `CASE` statement have the same output value.

Comment: I had a similar situation where I was trying to conditionally convert a column to decimal based on the column contents.  I was getting this error until I casted my decimal results back to varchar.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
SELECT ( CASE WHEN (@FQTROQ is not null and @FQTROQ <> '')
THEN ( @FQTROQ )
ELSE ( CAST(@FQNUTQ AS VARCHAR(30))) END ) AS Numero_Troquel
```

because the returned value from a column needs to match, SQL Server will try to convert your VARCHAR to a NUMERIC, not the other way around, which is what you probably want.

What's with that naming convention, btw?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have 2 variables of different types, and even though you're only trying to return ONE of those values as "Numero_Troquel", they have to be compatible types. What it's doing is trying to convert the @FQTROQ variable into a DECIMAL.

You'd either need to do:

```
SELECT ( CASE WHEN (@FQTROQ is not null and @FQTROQ <> '')
THEN ( @FQTROQ )
ELSE ( CAST(@FQNUTQ AS VARCHAR(30)) ) END ) AS Numero_Troquel
```

OR...

```
IF (@FQTROQ is not null and @FQTROQ <> '')
    SELECT @FQTROQ AS Numero_Troquel -- this will return as a VARCHAR
ELSE
    SELECT @FQNUTQ AS Numero_Troquel -- this will return as a DECIMAL
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Easy answer I didn't know